# Animation Group Order

Tags: animation-nodes

Using animation nodes I was able to make a procedural animation of a bridge made up of tiles coming from above and forming said bridge.

I created it by taking a plane, subdividing it 10 times, separating the faces, made them separate objects and added them to a group. 
I use said group in a loop subprogram for the animation.

The issue arises when the tiles come in, they come in at a weird order. I wanted to know if there is a way to control the order of which the tiles(objects) come in? Is that possible or would I have to connect hundred of objects in the correct order in an object list.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The question is specific about sorting the order. But I see several ways here, depending on the case. For precision: are the tiles the same or have to be slightly different? Is the grid original order OK or you need another ? (the group is not reliable as order) A pic of the loop or how you animate the positions falling would help too.

Comment: I have not gotten a chance to take some screenshots but will do as soon as I can. As of right now I'd be fine if they were all the same. Grid order is great! but would ultimately like some control ( making it come in from back to front or middle outwards. ) 

I know a picture is better but I'm using a compose matrix to control the transformations. Using a animate matrix  with a time delay to make they come in one at a time. 

Sorry for the lack of picture but I will get one soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, blender group is not reliable as objects order.

Otherwise, you need a fixed location of objects as a reference for sorting by location.
Given that they are moving around you have to consider only the final position (landed) for sorting.

This goes 2 ways:

- you use instancer to copy same object. Here **you need to sort the vectors** positions (vector list) that give the location of objects (instances), and not the objects
- if have a list/group of objects that are different, you have to use id key node (object submenu) to get the initial rot/loc . But first, make sure you set initial transforms (in 3d view, AN panel) for all objects.
  *This is slightly different and I'll not detail here.*

**I will detail the first case**

For the examples below I use the template Grid Arrange.

1. Just use the grid order
   This goes naturally if u use the respective template or similar.

[image]

2. Use a distance to object to sort
   In comparison to above, use a vector/ vector distance node to compare each position to an empty (or something else)

[image]

3. U can further use some expressions
   U can do the same by sorting the vector (landed positions) first
   as distance to or as direction as shown in the pics with formula:

distance to:

```
sorted(list, key = lambda item: (item - point).length_squared, reverse = reversed)
```

direction:

```
sorted(list, key = lambda item: item.dot(direction), reverse = reversed)
```

where the inputs are: a vector list, a vector, a boolean

[image]

[image]

Please note that in all these case I basically sort the vectors, not the objects. 
For the other case, you would sort the objects based on the list of (id key ) initial locations.

Comment: Hey! o.g. Thank you so much for the detailed and quick answer! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm getting pretty serious with animation nodes and aim to fully incorporate it with my work flow. I will be asking many more questions in the future.  Thank you again for answering!

Comment: You're welcome. Please do ask more. Ideally, the q would be specific and maybe even illustrated :)